# How to remove some items from an arraylist without loop and less time complexity?

Tags: performance, loops, arraylist, java-8, time-complexity

I have an array list of 100 000 objects. I want to remove some of the objects which have a particular ID. I'm using for loop to search through the `ArrayList` and remove each of them. Hence it is very much time-consuming. Is there any possible way to do this without any looping?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what Java version are you running? Java 8 or higher?

Comment: @deHaar, i have tried in Android with java 8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
List<Type> list = ...
list.removeIf(item -> item.getId() == something);
```

As the name suggests, `removeIf()` removes all elements if they satisfy the predicate.

Comment: Is this having less time complexity?

Comment: @AkhilAravind No!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose okay

Comment: Time complexity is linear. AFAIK impossible to do better than that.

Comment: Thanks. It's the answer i was looking for

Comment: Time complexity of `removeIf` is linear (so is `removeAll` with a set or small collection argument), but [as elaborated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57094996/2711488), removing objects in a loop, as needed when having to check the ID, is worse than linear. So, using `removeIf` *has* a performance benefit.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose compared to looping over the list and removing elements, it *has* better time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know the structure of your `Lakh` class, I can only provide an example using `String`s:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    words.add("I");
    words.add("want");
    words.add("to");
    words.add("remove");
    words.add("things");
    words.add("without");
    words.add("a");
    words.add("loop");

    System.out.println("———— BEFORE ————");
    words.forEach(word -> System.out.println(word));

    System.out.println("———— AFTER ————");
    // this is the removal action, it removes all entries that equal certain words
    words.removeIf(word -> word.equals("loop") || word.equals("remove"));

    words.forEach(word -> System.out.println(word));
}
```

> Please not that this will use a loop under the hood, too. More precise:
>   An `Iterator<E>` in a `while` loop.

Comment: @Adrian thanks, I wasn't able to extract that from the context *1 Lakh objects* but it's beginning to make sense ;-)

Comment: The `default` implementation of `removeIf` uses an iterator based loop, but `ArrayList` overrides this method with a far better implementation, suited to the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use remove() method like below:

```
List<String> nameList = ArrayList<String>();
nameList.add("Sam");
nameList.add("Sarah");

//Remove by index
nameList.remove(0);

//Remove by value
nameList.remove("Sarah");
```

Comment: remove only removes the first occurrence of the object