# Remove a value from ArrayList<Custom> without running a loop

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a list of CustomObject and I wish to remove a value from the list with same id(property of CustomObject). 
Now this can be done by using loop. But that seems a very unnecessary and inefficient code to me.  Is there any other way to get specific object with id?

Comment: I think you can override the hash code(It's my Preference) for CustomObject and then you can use remove(customObject) method of List.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57356695/7666442

Comment: use this code --> list.remove(new Custom());

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove some items from an arraylist without loop and less time complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57356584/how-to-remove-some-items-from-an-arraylist-without-loop-and-less-time-complexity)

Comment: @ManojPerumarath no

Answer (score 0):

If your project's **min sdk version** is 24 and up then you can use `removeIf`

```
yourList.removeIf(model -> model.id == yourid);
```

> If you check the code inside `removeIf`, actually it also iterate
>   throughout the list to remove matching object.

Beside this, if you are using **Kotlin** or want to, Then you can filter the list with your `id` and then remove those from your list.

```
val yourList = arrayListOf<Model>()

val removeList = yourList.filter { model ->
    model.id == yourid
}

yourList.removeAll(removeList)
```

Comment: @Parth, did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `removeIf` method, you can do something like this:

```
yourList.apply { removeAt( first { it.id == id } ) }
```