# Is it possible to use Collections.removeAll() by also passing self-defined equals() method in Java?

Tags: java, collections

Consider I have a Java object `Student` only with getters and setters that I cannot change, and two Lists – `students1` and `students2` – both of type `ArrayList<Student>`.

How can I call `students1.removeAll(students2)` by passing my own `equals()` method?

This is because I cannot modify the `Student` class.

Comment: You could iterate through the collection and remove the items that match whatever criteria you care about.

Comment: `Stream.filter()`?

Comment: `Stream.filter()` will require stream inside stream, I think it'll be inefficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well one option might be to use the decorator pattern here, and just wrap the `Student` class in a new class which then overrides the `equals()` method with whatever new logic you want, e.g.

```
public class YourStudent {
    private Student instance;

    public YourStudent() { ... }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `removeIf` and `stream`

```
students1.removeIf(stu1->students2.stream()
                                  .anyMatch(stu2->stu2.getId().equals(stu1.getId()) && /* other properties */ );
```

Comment: Stream inside stream. Isn't it inefficient?

Comment: removeIf i using iterator https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collection.java#L539 and since you can't override `equals()` method this will be the best way @misteeque

Comment: @misteeque `listA.removeAll(listB)` is no faster. Both are `O(n*m)`.

Comment: `removeIf` is the right thing, however, to avoid the O(n×m) time complexity, you should collect the Ids from `students2` into a `Set` first, e.g. `Set<IdType> set = students2.stream().map(Student::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet()); students1.removeIf(st -> set.contains(st.getId()));`

Comment: @Deadpool the `default` implementation uses an `Iterator`, but `ArrayList` overrides it with an implementation which is significantly more efficient than an `Iterator` based operation could ever be. This has been described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57094996/2711488).

Comment: @Holger I agree collecting Student id's into `Set` but OP did not mentioned what properties that he need to check to find duplicates.

Comment: You can always replace ID by an object holding all relevant properties. This can be a dedicated class or just `List` as an ad-hoc key type , e.g. `Set<List<?>> set = students2.stream().map(st -> Arrays.asList(st.getProperty1(),st.getProperty2())).collect(Collectors.toSet()); students1.removeIf(st -> set.contains(Arrays.asList(st.getProperty1(),st.getProperty2())));`

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your list to a stream and use the filter method, for example:

```
List<Student> filteredStudents = students2
    .stream().filter(s -> s.getName().compareTo("John")) // Write your filter
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>()));

students1.removeAll(students2);
```

Edit to explain what to do with students2.

Comment: Since the OP is modifying the list in-place, your approach gives different results than what was asked for. However, often it is a bad idea to modify a collection in place, so you could improve your answer by highlighting this difference and explaining when your method might be a better option than say, [`removeIf()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59952456/3474)

Comment: Sorry but I don't know if I undertand what you mean by the difference between my answer and removeIf(). Do you refer to ConcurrentModificationException?

Comment: In your solution, you're comparing each item with a `constant` value, `John`, while in my case, I'll have to write another stream there, because I will compare each item with a list of items. I was expecting something that does not require me to  use stream inside a stream.

Comment: I think I did not explain well enough. My idea was to use the filter method to create a new List with the elements that match your "equal" condition. Then pass this list to students1.removeAll(filteredStudents). Do you know the equal implementation of Student class? Does the removeAll remove all the elements that match students2?

Comment: No, I mean that in the OP's example, the contents of the `List students1` is modified. But in your approach, the original list is unchanged, and a new list is created and assigned to `filteredStudents`. This can be a big difference if others have a reference to the original list, which could be good or bad, depending on the context.

Comment: @erickson I edited my answer to explain a bit better. The point of `filteredStudents` is, if there is any student left, pass this list to `student1.removeAll` and then you would remove those students from `student1`. The result of this relies on the implementation of `Student.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java 8? If yes, you could consider using Collection::removeIf with a lambda expression containing your custom equality check.

If you're forced to use Java 7 or below, then you'll probably have to create a new class extending Student if you want to stick with Collections::removeAll.

Another option would be to loop through your lists manually, removing everything from the first list that matches any element of your second list (Watch out though, since this will be a concurrent modification and may throw Exceptions if not implemented correctly).